# How to Find the location of a number in a table in C?

Tags: c, binary, binary-search

Got a problem with binary search in C. I have an array of 100 numbers thats divided to 10 lines and 10 columns. If someone writes a number in and the number exist in the table so the program should print out the exact location of the number (Line and column the number is in), but the problem is now that it only work on number that is located in the first line. i don't get the right positions of the rest.

I am quite new to C and it is my first time working with binary search so appreciate the help.

```c
void siffra(int tal[99], int val, int first, int last, int middle){
    printf("Enter the value to find:\n");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    first = 0;
    last = val - 1;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    while (first <= last) {
        if (tal[middle] < val)
            first = middle + 1;    
        else if (tal[middle] == val) {
            printf("%d is present at Line %d Column %d.\n", val, last, middle+1);
            break;
        }
        else
            last = middle - 1;
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", val);  
}
```

Comment: If its a single 10x10 array the row is loc / 10, the column within that row is loc % 10. And I honestly don't understand the purpose of half the arguments provided to your function. Fyi, its ok to actually declare local automatic variables. The universe doesn't need to be passed in an formal parameter list. ex: `first`, `last`, and `middle` are *all* worthless as function arguments here, and `i` isn't even used *at all*. You also mentioned nothing about the sorting of the table itself. For you algorithm to work no row can have numbers  smaller than any row prior, and all rows must be sorted.

Comment: I also question logic like `last = val - 1;`  um.. `val` is the value you're hunting for. `last` is a stopping point for a partition. The former has nothing to do with the latter.

Comment: There are 4 options user have. 1: generate numbers, 2:it sorts by bubble sort, 3: Average, highest and lowest, 4: is to look in to a number in the list.

Comment: Changes nothing I mentioned in either of my prior comments, especially the second one. That initial value of `last` makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this statement `last = val - 1;`

`first` is initialised to 0 because `tal[0]` is the first element of the array.

In the same way `last` should be initiated so that `tal[last]` would be the last element of the array.

Since your array counts 99 elements ( you wrote it here `void siffra(int tal[99], ...`) last should be 98. However you said you want 10 lines and 10 rows, which means 100 elements. So you should have `int tal[100]` and `last` should be initiated to 99.

One last thing: you initialize `first`, `middle` and `last` in the function, so you didn't need to pass any particular value through them, thus you can declare them directly into the function, as local variables.

Comment: I tried to change that since to int last = tal[99] and now it just says the number is not in the list.

Comment: No for now you need `last = 98;` because `tal` has 99 elements. However you should change `tal` to have 100 elements `int tal[100]` and after you do that, you need `last = 99;`

Comment: Oh Thanks, It works now but there is a problem that it is not divided to 10 rows and 10 columns but instead it it continues to 100. 
Ex
If a number is in second row, first column, It says that the number is in line 11 column 11.

Comment: Oh yes, but the principle is the same. You got 100 elements, so it should be `int tal[100]`. The first element is `tal[0]` and the last one `tal[99]`

Comment: Well yh but that bit is part of my assignment I mean to show which row and column the number is located. I got it when I tried linear searching but I should use binary searching.

Comment: The row of `tal[x]` is is `x/10` and the column is `x%10` note that you start counting rows and columns from 0

Comment: Can You be more specific where to use them ?

Comment: You don't have to use them. But let's say you want to show in which column is located `tal[32]`, then you just do `printf("%d", 32%10);` that's it

Comment: I finally got it work but still two problems. 1. The rows starts from 0 and in my printf I tried to do (last/10)+1 but If a number is located in the 6th column of first row it shows second row. 2. Numbers in last column (10) are 0. Dont know why!

Comment: If you want to start from 1 instead of 0, then do `(last+1)/10`